# Dovecot Unable to access letsencrypt certificates on LEMP server

Tags: ssl-certificate, email-server, dovecot, lets-encrypt

I am attempting to setup postfix and dovecot on a LEMP server. I am using letsencrypt certificates. I suspect I am having a permissions problem because I cannot access the `/etc/letsencrypt/live` folder using `cd` unless I preface it with the `sudo su` command.

This seems to be affecting my dovecot configuration because dovecot is giving me the following fatal error:

> doveconf: Fatal: Error in configuration file
>   /etc/dovecot/conf.d/10-ssl.conf line 13: ssl_key: Can't open file
>   /etc/letsencrpyt/

I have checked my letsencrypt certificate and pemchain path in dovecot settings multiple times and they are correct. So it appears that something else is blocking dovecot from accessing my certificate chain. I'm assuming it is the same thing that won't let me access my chain with out being root.

The Top of my /etc/dovecot/conf.d/10-ssl.conf page looks like this:

```
##
## SSL settings
##

# SSL/TLS support: yes, no, required. <doc/wiki/SSL.txt>
ssl = required

# PEM encoded X.509 SSL/TLS certificate and private key. They're opened before
# dropping root privileges, so keep the key file unreadable by anyone but
# root. Included doc/mkcert.sh can be used to easily generate self-signed
# certificate, just make sure to update the domains in dovecot-openssl.cnf
ssl_cert = </etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.mysite.com/fullchain.pem
ssl_key = </etc/letsencrpyt/live/mail.mysite.com/privkey.pem
```

My /etc/dovecot/conf.d/10-ssl.conf has the following lines uncommented and edited. I am not actually using mail.mysite.com :

```
ssl = required
ssl_cert = </etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.mysite.com/fullchain.pem
ssl_key = </etc/letsencrpyt/live/mail.mysite.com/privkey.pem
ssl_client_ca_dir = /etc/ssl/certs
ssl_dh = </usr/share/dovecot/dh.pem
```

The Results of:

```
ls -l /etc | grep letsencrypt
drwxr-xr-x  9 root  root     4096 Feb 20 12:44 letsencrypt
```

My question is, how can I fix the above error and allow dovecot to access my letsencrypt certificate path correctly?

Comment: Show your dovecot configuration lines. Permissions shouldn't be problem, because dovecot opens these files while running as root.

Comment: And also - what are permissions on `/etc/letsencrypt`? Show result of this command `ls -l /etc | grep letsencrypt`.

Comment: I updated the question to include the requested information.

Answer (score 0):

Damn spelling. :) Didn't catch this myself first time. You have `letsencrPYt` in your config, and it's clearly shown in error message as well.

Comment: Wow! Thank you!!!!!!!!

Comment: Homer simpson 'Doh'! Thankyou thank you! I have been going over this for days! Somehow I totally looked over the spelling! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

To solve this, I just had to spell `ssl_key = </etc/letsencrpyt` correctly for my ssl_key.

The proper syntax is:

```
ssl_key = </etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.mysite.com/privkey.pem
```

NOT

```
ssl_key = </etc/letsencrpyt/live/mail.mysite.com/privkey.pem
```